# Strange javascript occurrence in xampp

Tags: javascript, html

For some strange reason the following jfiddle works in my XAMPP: https://jsfiddle.net/mxba760w/  Obviously the top and bottom div are incomplete and should not be there; However when I remove them, the code ISN'T working.

HTML code:

```
    <form action="" class="search-form">
            <div class="cell">
                <input type="text" name="q" onClick="action();"/>
            </div>
            <div class="cell button-holder">
                <button type="submit" id="dropdownbutton">
                    <span>Search</span> 
                </button>    
            </div>
        </form>
```

CSS:

```
.search-form {
display: table;
border: 5px solid red;
background: #fff;
margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

.search-form .cell {
display:table-cell; 
vertical-align:middle;
}

.search-form input {
font-size: 1.3em;
height: 50px;
border: none;
}

.search-form button {
display:block;
border: none;
background-color: red;
height: 50px;
vertical-align: top;
cursor: pointer;
}

.button-holder {
background-color: red;
}

#dropdownbutton{
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

JavaScript

```
function action() {
        document.getElementById('dropdownbutton').style.visibility =     'visible';
    }
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: There might be a naming collision with using "action" in the context of a form, that has an "action" try renaming the function to something else e.g. "otherAction"

Comment: @scunliffe - you were spot on, that was it; i would never have got that; i was tearing my hair out.  thanks a lot

Comment: @cricket_007 the case of onclick vs onClick will both work.. and unless this developer has disabled it, it will respond to a click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the browser executes the code in your `onclick="..."` event handler, it looks for a reference named `action` that can satisfy your event.

Due to the way that the browser "looks" for a potential match, it looks in the current form (due to this being a form element), then in the global window (which is where your function lives).

Since the form has an "action" attribute, it becomes the first reference found.  Unfortunately attempting to call it will fail (since it isn't a function/method)

I'd highly advise to not name any global functions that have similar names to any very common names used elsewhere. In this case calling your function `"someAction"` or any other name should fix the issue.